# Why System Macro Functions (FireDAC) Not Working?

Tags: delphi, macros, firedac

I am trying to execute some [System Macro Functions](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/System_Macro_Functions_(FireDAC)) in MySQL and MSSQL in FireDAC, but it gives me this message:

[FireDAC][Phys]-327. Escape function [DATABASE] is not supported

Select { Database() }
Select { User() }
Select { NEWGUID( ) }

Comment: FireDAC just does some text replacement in the SQL before sending it to the server. Can you log what the server receives?

Comment: Searching through the FireDac source files shows this is error string `S_FD_AccEscapeIsnotSupported`, issued on error `er_FD_AccEscapeIsnotSupported`, from `TFDPhysConnectionMetadata.UnsupportedEscape`. Set a breakpoint there and investigate what is going on. You'll probably see that the error originates in either `FireDAC.Phys.MSSQLMeta.pas` or `FireDAC.Phys.MySQLMeta.pas`.